# Conditional UI expression (Maximo)

Tags: conditional-statements, maximo, maximo-anywhere

I was doing a course in Maximo through Udemy. In Conditional expression, the instructor was using signature option along side with Conditional UI. Could anyone please elaborate on the Signature option? why do we need to use it with conditional UI configuration?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzutJ.png)

The following image has question I'm seeking answer for

Answer (score 1):

Since OOTB Maximo lacks a simpler way to do date validation that is any more complicated than "yes, you could find that date on a calendar", most people would use an automation script on the Validate event of an attribute launch point. They would use an automation script because Conditional UI *only* works with the UI, and that type of validation should normally also apply to data arriving via integration.

If your question is more generally about why we need to use Signature Options to do Conditional UI, welcome to the club. Given an RFE to decouple Conditional UI from Security was rejected, the reason we need Sig Options to do Conditional UI seems to be: that is the vendor's prerogative.